# Django: merge text from the form and from the database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am currently working with one Django project.

And I have the dictionary in it:

from models.py

```
class teltab(models.Model):
    code=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    telescope=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment=models.TextField(blank=True)
```

and a form to add data to the dictionary:

```
class newtelescopesform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=teltab
```

And now I need to do the following:

- get the text (Сomment 1) from the database (I am running Postgresql),
- get the text (Сomment 2) from the form,
- combine the data (Сomment 1 + Сomment 2),
- and finally write the result to the database.

Namely my table looks like this

[image: Fig1]

and I want to get this

[image: Fig2]

So my code from views.py:

```
  if len(request.GET['comment'])>0:
     commentq=request.GET['comment'] # I expect that it will take the text from form
     p=tel_list.get('comment', "") # I expect that it will take the text from database 
     commentp = p + "\n" + commentq # and it should merge the text
     tel_list.update(comment=commentq)
     for item in tel_list: 
         item.save()
```

But it gives me an error message: **"too many values to unpack"**.

**My question is what am I doing wrong? What is the reason for the error?**

Please teach me an elegant solution to this problem.

(Sorry for the long text, I obviously do not know what am I doing).

Comment: You have defined a form, why don't use form instead of using `request.GET`?

Comment: Where in the execution does it give you the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly better off using a separate `Comment` model and forming a foreign key relationship with your original model.

```
class Teltab(models.Model): # it’s good python coding style to capitalize classnames
  code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  telescope = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Comment(models.Model):
  text = models.TextField(required=True)
  teltab = models.ForeignKey(Teltab)
```

Then you can obtain all the comments on your original model something like -

```
my_teltab = Teltab.objects.first()
my_teltab.comment_set.all()
```